# Is this the proper way to obtain a drag and drop file for the exe application created in C#?

Tags: c#, windows

Pretty much exactly what the title says. I created an exe windows form program in C# and i found how to obtain the file name and path that was dragged and dropped onto the exe. Well is this the proper way to obtain the file?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static String file;
        public Form1()
        {
            foreach (String arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
            {
                file = arg;
            }

            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = file;
        }
    }
}
```

It does work and if i run the program itself, it gives me the file path and name of the exe itself. But when dragging and dropping to the exe, it gives me the file that i dropped. Is this the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In general, `GetCommandLineArgs` may or may not contain path to executable as first argument. But in most cases - first argument will be your exe.

So, second, third and so on arguments will contains dropped files.

Hm, thought command line passed to the `main` method of main class in C#, no?

Comment: Yes you are correct. In does get passed to the `main` method of the main class like so `static void Main(string[] args)` which im sure you already knew. But thats mostly for console apps. But you can also use the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` as in my example above(which i like better) in a windows form program. Either way they return the same information. I thank you for clarifying that the first path will be to the executable and then the following will be dropped files. I just wasnt sure if thats just how it was. So thanks for reassuring me! :)

Comment: You should pass the command line parameters from `main` for better encapsulation. Otherwise you won't be able to use this form anywhere other than as the main form of an application.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am not sure i completely understand. What do you mean i wont be able to use this form anywhere other than as the main form? This is the main form.....

Comment: @Seth Someday you may want to use this form as a secondary form, but you won't be able to because of this dependency on the command line parameters. Or maybe someday you want to add command line options to your program. You won't be able to because this form will treat the options as file names.